# Multiple-choice answers not working

Tags: python

I'm creating a menu that is meant to look like this

```
1-quit
2-multiplication
3-division
```

I cannot seem to fix this error it has something to do with `random.randint`

What I've done so far:

```
iFirst= random.randint(1,10)
iSecond = random.randint (1,10)
import random
print(" Made by: Ahmed\n --------------------") 
print("1 - quit") 
print("2 - Multiplication")
print("3 - Division")

while 1: 
    choose=input("\n\t:") 
    if choose=="1": 
        break # we basically break the while loop so it stops 
    if choose=="2": 
        a=iFirst*iSecond
        print(str(iFirst) + "*" + str(iSecond))
        print("a") + (random.randint()1,10)
        print("a") + (random.randint()1,10)
        print("b") + (random.randint()1,10)
        print("c") + (str(a)   
    if choose =="3":
```

I'm trying to make it so that if I choose '2' it would randomly generate a multiplication question  with random answers, all different all the time, and the real answer wouldn't stay at a certain letter. eg. If answer was 'b' the next question will be different.

I want it to  go a little bit like this but I cannot because it's too challenging for me.

```
5*4 = ?
a)10
b)32
c)20
d)42
```

I'm trying to make it so that it randomizes the numbers each time I push 2 or I get an incorrect answer. From there I can do the rest but at the moment it gives me an error that I cannot figure out because i'm a beginner in Python. I need help. I don't want you guys to do all of it for me because I know you're not meant to, you're only here to help people like me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to move the `import random` line _above_ the lines where you use `random.randint`.

Comment: and you have too many syntax errors here

Comment: Do I really? wow I must be bad at this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the answers into a `list` and then use `random.shuffle()`

```
>>> answers = [10, 32, 20, 42]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(answers)
>>> for c, item in zip('abcd', answers):
...     print("{}) {}".format(c, item))
... 
a) 20
b) 32
c) 10
d) 42
```

shuffle again gives a different order

```
>>> random.shuffle(answers)
>>> for c, item in zip('abcd', answers):
...     print("{}) {}".format(c, item))
... 
a) 32
b) 20
c) 42
d) 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This `(random.randint()1,10)` should be `random.randint(1,10)` (just like you had it above). You should also move the `import random` line to the top of your file.

You should also fix your print statements, here is a better approach:

```
print('{}*{}'.format(iFirst,iSecond))
print('a) {}'.format(random.randint(1,10)))
print('b) {}'.format(random.randint(1,10)))
print('c) {}'.format(a))
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives me an error on  print('b) {}'.format(random.randint(1,10))